# Error drawing vertex buffer object

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I have an Android application, that render some 3D-model, loaded from OBJ-file. At first I try to render only vertices (without normals and texture-coord info).

After loading OBJ-file vertices to vector of triangles I try to create VBO:

```
struct obj_model_t {
    GLuint vertex_buf;
    GLuint tex_coord_buf;
    GLuint normals_buf;
    unsigned int count;
};

...
obj_model_t out_model;
// loading triangles to std::vector<glm::vec3> out_vertices;
glGenBuffers(1, &out_model.vertex_buf);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, out_model.vertex_buf);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * out_vertices.size(), &out_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And then, in render function I try to bind this VBO and draw triangles from that:

```
void engine_t::render(double elapsedTime) {
    // clear buffer and other preparations for render

    mat4 mvp = camera_.projection_matrix() * camera_.view_matrix();
    glUseProgram(gProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_uMVPMatrix_Handle, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model_.vertex_buf);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(g_vPosition_Handle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    glVertexAttribPointer(g_vPosition_Handle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model_.count); // E/Adreno200-ES20(27772): gl_draw_error_checks:418>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays"); // after glDrawArrays glError (0x502)

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(g_vPosition_Handle);
    checkGlError("glDisableVertexAttribArray");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

But if I replace `out_vertices` from loading function to global space and use:

```
 glVertexAttribPointer(g_vPosition_Handle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)&out_vertices[0]);
```

without binding `model_.vertex_buf` (without call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model_.vertex_buf);`) my model renders normally.

How I can fix this problem and use VBO to draw my vertices?

Comment: Can you check all the values in your model_ check out: Count has a positive value and vertex_buf has a valid ID. It might be there is an error in your model object or possibly you create the buffer too early in your pipeline and the buffer does not even exist.

Comment: Count of vertices is a positive number. Buffer always creates successfully, but when I try draw vertices from VBO, glDrawArrays crash with "E/Adreno200-ES20(27772): gl_draw_error_checks:418>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION".